# Homing Missiles, How Do They Work?

Tags: c#, geometry, xna, 2d, game-physics

**What I am trying to create**

- An object that will launch a missile towards the player, if it collides with player, player dies.

**The Problem**

- How does the missile move towards the player.
- How do I make the missile move so that it does not instantly move directly towards the player(to slowly move on an angle).

I have a formula for the mouse to be the "Player" and the missile to go towards it.

```
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        mousePosition = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);

        A = (mouse.X - Position.X);
        B = (mouse.Y - Position.Y);
        C = (A * A) + (B * B);

        C = (float)Math.Sqrt(C);

        Angle1 = A / C;
        Angle2 = B / C;
```

[image: A Right Triangle with Angles]

(Drawing is the best!)

This only gets the distance from missile to player, now I need to find the angle or something to move the missile, what do I need to do?

Comment: Math.Atan2 will return the angle to you. You can then offset it based on a small amount (angle) so it doesn't go directly at the player.

Comment: I'm thinking: an introductory book on control theory...

Comment: Ok but how do I move the object, I kind of just a little stuck on how to say it in the program.

Comment: Move it by speed at angle.

Comment: May I please see an example, I understand that I must move it at that angle but how do I set it up like that? Sorry I am still kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: take current vector2 + new vector2(speed * Cos(angle), speed * Sin(angle))
Unless i switched the sin and cos around.
Also this site is for helping with coding not for making code for others. Next time show us what you have tried.

Comment: I did not need you to make the code I just need to know how the function works. Thank you for helping I will try this deathismyfreind.

Comment: Look into Linear Interpolation (Lerp), or Tweening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the distance from one point to another, and turn that into a direction to go to.

```
//Find the delta time
float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 60;
//Find the direction
Vector2 direction = mousePosition - misslePosition;
direction.Normalize();
//Move towards it
currentPos += direction * delta;
```

It needs to be multiplied by the elapsed time so it appears the same no matter what FPS you are running at.

You may need to adjust for speed, but it should create a pattern like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPJ3B.png]

If you would like the missle to slowly turn towards the target, you can experiment with `MathHelper.Lerp` to slowly change the angle.

Comment: Homing missiles without inertia aren't much fun.  How are you supposed to dodge them?