# MathHelper.Lerp Homing Missile

Tags: c#, math, xna, rotation

I was in need of help about creating a homing missile that would go towards the target I was given information and was able to do so but I have been looking into MathHelper.Lerp, that I was directed to try and use [on the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690424/homing-missiles-how-do-they-work), and have not found a reliable way to rotate the direction of the missile.

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        mousePosition = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);

        delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * Speed;

        direction = mousePosition - missilePosition;
        direction.Normalize();
        missilePosition += direction * delta;

        d.X = mouse.X - missilePosition.X;
        d.Y = mouse.Y - missilePosition.Y;

        distance = Math.Sqrt((d.X * d.X) + (d.Y * d.Y));

        v.X += d.X * turning;
        v.X += d.X * turning;

        Velocity = Math.Sqrt((v.X * v.X) + (v.Y * v.Y));
```

How would I use lerp to rotate the direction so the missile turns slowly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this when calculating the direction you want your missile to head in:

```
Vector2 direction = Vector2.Lerp(mousePosition, missilePosition, 0.5f);
```

This will get a direction that is 50% towards the direction you want.